# How to get a Vlookup to populate with an IF Statement, or visvera?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have IF Statement

`=IF('[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2-B2<0,'[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1,IF('[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$2-B2<0,'[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1,IF('[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2-B2<0,'[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1,"GOOD")))`

This is doing a subtraction of ordered quantity from inventory on hand by week. If the quantity is < 0 then it tells me the week number in the column header. If it does not go less then 0 it moves to the next column/week.

I need to incorporate a `VLOOKUP` in to this. So my lookup_value is the item number, when it locates the item on the second spread sheet, I need it to run my `IF formula`. This would tell me if the order is `GOOD`, or have it populate with the corresponding week number `[Mtch Index.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1`.

I thought maybe utilizing an index formula to help, but cannot work out the logic myself. Anyone have some thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this?:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(lookup_value,range,col_index,0),"",IF FORMULA HERE)
```

I didn't know the details so i provided generic arguments.